# Ubuntu Preseed, why is grub looking for a volume group called sda?

Tags: server, grub2, uefi, preseed

I'm trying to preseed install Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS but I'm encountering an error where grub2 causes the installer to abort (red background). The text of the error is "An installation step failed. You can try to run the failing item again from the menu or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is 'Install the GRUB bootloader to a hard disk.'.
Here's my preseed file:

```
### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.UTF-8

# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string gb

### Network configuration
# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# Just in case our DHCP server is busy.
d-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 60

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

# Added by @analytically: always install the server kernel
d-i     base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server

### Mirror settings
# Alternatively: by default, the installer uses CC.archive.ubuntu.com where
# CC is the ISO-3166-2 code for the selected country. You can preseed this
# so that it does so without asking.
d-i mirror/http/mirror select gb.archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/proxy string

### Clock and time zone setup
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
"custom-cd/new-iso/preseed/ps-lubuntu-server.seed" [dos] 243L, 10212C                                                                                                                                                   1,1           Top
### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.UTF-8

# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string gb

### Network configuration
# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# Just in case our DHCP server is busy.
d-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 60

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

# Added by @analytically: always install the server kernel
d-i     base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server

### Mirror settings
# Alternatively: by default, the installer uses CC.archive.ubuntu.com where
# CC is the ISO-3166-2 code for the selected country. You can preseed this
# so that it does so without asking.
d-i mirror/http/mirror select gb.archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/proxy string

### Clock and time zone setup
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string Etc/UTC

# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

####----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Partitioning
### Do NOT install on the USB stick(!)
#
# The Debian installer will install on the first disk it finds which can
# sometimes be the USB stick itself. Work around this by rolling our own auto
# detect logic which disallows installing on USB devices.
d-i partman/early_command string \
  USBDEV_LIST="$(mktemp)"; \
  list-devices usb-partition | sed "s/\(.*\)./\1/" > "$USBDEV_LIST"; \
  BOOTDEV="$(list-devices disk | grep -vf "$USBDEV_LIST" | head -n 1)"; \
  debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$BOOTDEV"; \
  debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev "$BOOTDEV";

### Partitioning

#uto method must be lvm
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false

# Keep that one set to true so we end up with a UEFI enabled
# system. If set to false, /var/lib/partman/uefi_ignore will be touched
d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean true

# enforce usage of GPT - a must have to use EFI!
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt

d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root-all
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
boot-root-all :: \
538 538 1075 free \
$iflabel{ gpt } \
$reusemethod{ } \
method{ efi } \
format{ } \
. \
128 512 256 ext2 \
$defaultignore{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } \
mountpoint{ /boot } \
. \
1024 4096 15360 ext4 \
$lvmok{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
mountpoint{ / } \
. \
1024 4096 15360 ext4 \
$lvmok{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
mountpoint{ /var } \
. \
1024 1024 -1 ext4 \
$lvmok{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
mountpoint{ /var/lib } \
.
# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string /dev/sda

###----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Base system installation
### Account setup

# To create a normal user account.

# The installer will warn about weak passwords. If you are sure you know
# what you're doing and want to override it, uncomment this.
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true

# Set to true if you want to encrypt the first user's home directory.
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

### Apt setup
# You can choose to install restricted and universe software, or to install
# software from the backports repository.
#d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
#d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
#d-i apt-setup/backports boolean true
# Uncomment this if you don't want to use a network mirror.
#d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
# Select which update services to use; define the mirrors to be used.
# Values shown below are the normal defaults.
#d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
#d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.com
#d-i apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu

# Additional repositories, local[0-9] available
#d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string \
#       http://local.server/ubuntu squeeze main
#d-i apt-setup/local0/comment string local server
# Enable deb-src lines
#d-i apt-setup/local0/source boolean true
# URL to the public key of the local repository; you must provide a key or
# apt will complain about the unauthenticated repository and so the
# sources.list line will be left commented out
#d-i apt-setup/local0/key string http://local.server/key

### Package selection
#tasksel        tasksel/force-tasks     string server
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect none
# Individual additional packages to install
d-i pkgsel/include string bash-completion openssh-server nfs-common xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 xorg xinit \
openbox roxterm xterm xfonts-wqy fonts-wqy-zenhei cpuburn pulseaudio acpid avahi-autoipd wget wput \
alsa-base alsa-utils libx86-dev uml-utilities plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo mingetty feh expect libyajl2 \
libasound2 libasound2-dev libasound2-plugins libgtk2.0-dev libnss3 libsdl1.2-dev libva-dev libudev-dev \
libssl-dev arping ibus-libpinyin ntpdate xdotool bridge-utils libevent-dev ibus-pinyin supervisor zip \
i2c-tools libnuma-dev smartmontools ftplib-dev bc iw wpasupplicant thin-provisioning-tools \
pm-utils ebtables cgmanager augeas-lenses libaugeas0 libboost-iostreams1.58.0 libboost-random1.58.0 \
libboost-thread1.58.0 libnetcf1 libnl-route-3-200 librados2 librbd1 libxen-4.6 libxenstore3.0
# Whether to upgrade packages after debootstrap.
# Allowed values: none, safe-upgrade, full-upgrade
#d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade

# Language pack selection
d-i pkgsel/language-packs multiselect en

# No language support packages
d-i     pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false

# Policy for applying updates. May be "none" (no automatic updates),
# "unattended-upgrades" (install security updates automatically), or
# "landscape" (manage system with Landscape).
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades

# Verbose output and no boot splash screen
d-i     debian-installer/quiet  boolean false
d-i     debian-installer/splash boolean false

### Boot loader installation
# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.         
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true

# This one makes grub-installer install to the MBR if it also finds some other
# OS, which is less safe as it might not be able to boot that other OS.
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

# Wait for two seconds in grub
d-i     grub-installer/timeout string 0

# Use the following option to add additional boot parameters for the
# installed system (if supported by the bootloader installer).
# Note: options passed to the installer will be added automatically.
d-i debian-installer/add-kernel-opts string vga=normal nomodeset audit=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=1 cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1

### Finishing up the installation
# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

#### Advanced options
### Running custom commands during the installation
# d-i preseeding is inherently not secure. Nothing in the installer checks
# for attempts at buffer overflows or other exploits of the values of a
# preconfiguration file like this one. Only use preconfiguration files from
# trusted locations! To drive that home, and because it's generally useful,
# here's a way to run any shell command you'd like inside the installer,
# automatically.

# This first command is run as early as possible, just after
# preseeding is read.
#d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install some-udeb
# This command is run immediately before the partitioner starts. It may be
# useful to apply dynamic partitioner preseeding that depends on the state
# of the disks (which may not be visible when preseed/early_command runs).
#d-i partman/early_command \
#       string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"
# This command is run just before the install finishes, but when there is
# still a usable /target directory. You can chroot to /target and use it
# directly, or use the apt-install and in-target commands to easily install
# packages and run commands in the target systemo.
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target update-grub;
```

Here's what /var/log/syslog says when the installer stops:

```
Jul  17 03:43:14 main-menu[273]: (process:26338): Volume group "sda" not found
Jul  17 03:43:14 main-menu[273]: (process:26338):
Jul  17 03:43:14 main-menu[273]: (process:26338):
Jul  17 03:43:14 main-menu[273]: (process:26338): Cannot process volume group sda
Jul  17 03:43:14 main-menu[273]: (process:26338):
Jul  17 03:43:14 main-menu[273]: WARNING **: Configuring 'grub-installer' failed with error code 1
Jul  17 03:43:14 main-menu[273]: WARNING **: Menu item 'grub-installer' failed.
```

I think I preinstalled some deb(xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 xorg) packages that caused the kernel to be modified.The device's UUID has changed,so the device cannot be started.I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it chooses `sda` because you specified

```
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string /dev/sda
```